# Print the values in an array using batch

Tags: batch-file, scripting, batch-processing

The following code lists all the folders in a directory sorted by date and prints the latest folder in %a%

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "directory" /b /ad-h /t:c /od') DO SET a=%%i
echo Most recent subfolder: %a%
```

How do i print the second recent one? I tried using %a[1]% but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another method that show you how to populate array dynamically using a counter.

You can for example populate two arrays with names and full paths dynamically while we increment the counter into a loop forindo

```bat
@echo off
Title Print the values in an array using batch
Set "MasterFolder=C:\FRST"
Set "RecentFolder="
set /a "count=0"
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Rem Populate two arrays with names and full paths dynamically while we increment the counter
@FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('dir "%MasterFolder%" /b /ad-h /t:c /o-d') DO ( 
    if not defined RecentFolder (
        set /a "Count+=1"
        set "RecentFolderName[!Count!]=%%~na"
        set "RecentFolderPath[!count!]=%%~fa"
    )
)

Rem Display numbered Folders Names and full paths
color 0A & Mode 90,30 & cls & echo( 
@for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
   set "RecentName=[%%i] - !RecentFolderName[%%i]!"
   set "RecentFullPath=FullPath - "!RecentFolderPath[%%i]!""
   echo !RecentName!
   echo !RecentFullPath!
   echo --------------------------------------------------
)
Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set "a="
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "directory" /b /ad-h /t:c /o-d') DO if not defined a SET "a=%%i"
```

sets the latest

```
set "a="
FOR /F "skip=1delims=" %%i IN ('dir "directory" /b /ad-h /t:c /o-d') DO if not defined a SET "a=%%i"
```

sets the second-latest

sadly, `skip=0` is not implemented.

Please use meaningful variable-names.